# How to decode hashed string from SimpleMembership in the iOS client?

Tags: ios, azure, hash

I'm using Windows Azure Mobile Services and I'm receiving hashed data (NSString). It uses SimpleMembership to hash it so I need to decode it (to NSString) in the client. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: what do you want to decode the hash to?

Answer (score 1):

Hashing is a [one-way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function), not bijective like encryption. Consider the original message lost.

Typically you would use secondary input (the plaintext password attempt), perform the same set of hash operations, and compare the results to infer matching sources (like passwords) barring the (ideally very rare) hash collision.

> A cryptographic hash function is a hash function which is considered practically impossible to invert, that is, to recreate the input data from its hash value alone. These one-way hash functions have been called "the workhorses of modern cryptography".
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Could you perhaps add some additional context?

### Edit

With the comment below, what you need to do is pass the plaintext to the Azure instance for hashing and comparison with the hashed result. With their membership, there will be a stored procedure that will perform this operation for you.

However, *by design*, passwords are completely irretrievable until if/when weaknesses are found in their specific hashing algorithm. This is why security questions / email verification steps are required in these systems: *they don't actually know your password and cannot retrieve it for you*.

#### Example: 'TerribleHash'

Using 'TerribleHash', a terrible hash algorithm, User ID 1 registers. ASP Membership generates an IV/salt (initialization vector) of 'salt1234', they enter a password of 'password' (as so many do). 'salt1234password' is then TerribleHashed 5,000 times to give '8h'. '8h' doesn't actually contain the password or the IV at all.

To check if the user can log in, they enter their User ID (or unique Username/Email that maps injectively to a User ID) and password 'nope'. Their IV/salt 'salt1234' is retrived, and 'salt1234nope' is TerribleHashed 5,000 times to give '96'. **Login denied**. They try again with 'password', 'salt1234password' is TerribleHashed 5,000 times to give '8h', and **Access Granted**.

Of course, TerribleHash is a terrible algorithm and two characters is not enough entropy to avoid collisions and thus '91u4hfah9' may result in a 'valid' login (also hash to '8h'), so nobody would use TerribleHash and they would use something like SHA256/SHA512 with minuscule collision frequencies, but I used it to illustrate the point that **the hash contains neither the password nor the initialization vector**.

Comment: Perhaps I'm using a different terminology? I'm receiving a password made up of random characters from the mobile service and I need to know the exact password inputted. Example is I'm receiving something like a "AMe23423drfwsrdsfbbcsdf+/342==" and I need to decode it to it's (supposedly) original input which is "password". I hope I gave additional context. I described it as best that I could. Thanks!

Comment: Unless you want to wait a few centuries (or even a millennium) to brute force the hash on an iPhone, you cannot. Consider the original password lost in the hashed string and completely irretrievable.

Comment: I added an example to my answer to (hopefully) illustrate why it is you cannot 'decode' a hash.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the informative explanation. Too bad I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.